# Multiple loss functions interfere with each other when combined

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, loss-function

Python packages:

- python 3.8.18
- PyTorch 2.1.0
- numpy 1.24.3
- itertools

Optimizer: LBFGS

Neural network:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
import itertools


def gradients(outputs, inputs):
    return torch.autograd.grad(outputs, inputs, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(outputs), allow_unused=True, create_graph=True)


def to_numpy(input):
    if isinstance(input, torch.Tensor):
        return input.detach().cpu().numpy()
    elif isinstance(input, np.ndarray):
        return input
    else:
        raise TypeError('Unknown type of input, expected torch.Tensor or ' \
                        'np.ndarray, but got {}'.format(type(input)))


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
        self, x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, dy_dx: np.ndarray,
        iters: int, evals: int, choice: int
    ):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        device = torch.device("cuda:0")
        self.ls = 0

        self.__ITERS = iters
        self.__EVALS = evals
        self.__CHOICE = choice

        self.net_y1 = self.__network()
        self.net_y2 = self.__network()

        self.mse = nn.MSELoss().cuda("cuda:0")

        self._num = x.shape[0]

        self.x  = torch.tensor(x, dtype=torch.float32, requires_grad=True).reshape((self._num, 1)).to(device)
        self.y1 = torch.tensor(y, dtype=torch.float32, requires_grad=True).reshape((self._num, 1)).to(device)
        self.y2 = torch.tensor(dy_dx, dtype=torch.float32).reshape((self._num, 1)).to(device)
        
        self.optimizer = torch.optim.LBFGS(
            itertools.chain(self.net_y1.parameters(), self.net_y2.parameters()),
            lr=0.1,
            max_iter=self.__ITERS,
            max_eval=self.__EVALS,
            tolerance_grad=1e-9,
            tolerance_change=1e-11,
            line_search_fn="strong_wolfe"
        )
        
        self.iter = 0

    # ----------------------- BEGIN NETWORKS -----------------------
    def __network(self):
        net = nn.Sequential()
        net.add_module('Linear_layer_1', nn.Linear(1, 15))
        net.add_module('Tanh_layer_1', nn.Tanh())
        for num in range(2, 5):
            net.add_module('Linear_layer_%d' % (num), nn.Linear(15, 15))
            net.add_module('Tanh_layer_%d' % (num), nn.Tanh())
        net.add_module('Linear_layer_final', nn.Linear(15, 1))
        net = net.cuda("cuda:0")
        return net
    # ----------------------- END NETWORKS -----------------------

    # ----------------------- BEGIN FUNCTIONS -----------------------
    def function(self, x: torch.Tensor):
        y1 = self.net_y1(x)
        y2 = self.net_y2(x)
        return y1, y2
    # ----------------------- END FUNCTIONS -----------------------


    # -------------------------------------- CLOSURE --------------------------------------
    def closure0(self):
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        y1, y2 = self.function(self.x)
        self.ls = self.mse(y1, self.y1)
        self.ls.backward()
        self.iter += 1
        if not self.iter % 50:
            print("mse y1: {}".format(self.ls))
        return self.ls
    
    def closure1(self):
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        y1, y2 = self.function(self.x)
        self.ls = self.mse(y1, self.y1) + self.mse(y2, self.y2)
        self.ls.backward()
        self.iter += 1
        if not self.iter % 50:
            print(self.ls)
            print("mse y1: {};  mse y2: {}".format(self.mse(y1, self.y1), self.mse(y2, self.y2)))
        return self.ls
    # -------------------------------------- END CLOSURE --------------------------------------


    def train(self):
        """training"""
        self.net_y1.train()
        self.net_y2.train()
        if self.__CHOICE == 0:
            self.optimizer.step(closure=self.closure0)
        elif self.__CHOICE == 1:
            self.optimizer.step(closure=self.closure1)
```

Test:

```py
def main_procedure2():
    device = torch.device("cuda:0")
    x = np.linspace(0, 5, 50)
    y1 = 1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi) * np.exp(-(x*5)**2/2) * 2.5
    y2 = -31.25 * np.sqrt(2) * x * np.exp(-25*x**2/2) / np.sqrt(np.pi)

    model = Net(x, y1, y2, 1000, 1200, 1)
    model.train()

main_procedure2()
```

This is a simplified example of my problem. You can adjust the last parameter in `model = net(x, y1, y2, 1000, 1200, 1)` to switch between `closure1` and `closure2`.

The `closure1` only optimizes `y1` and the `closure2` optimize `y1 & y2` by simply adding them together.

My question is:

It is said that when adding different losses together they will still fit separately. However from the test sample I found the losses interfered with each other. In more complex cases some of them will even increase so that the other losses will decrease faster.

So, is there any way to optimize the multiple loss functions together but decouple them?